# Error while building CI2CV using cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am trying to build CI2CV on windows using cmake for the first time. I get below errors while building

"CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package):Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any of the following names:

```
OpenCVConfig.cmake
opencv-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed."

Tried to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to location where OpenCVConfig.cmake file resides also tried the same with OpenCV_DIR. But no luck.

Please let me know way out of this.

Comment: have you solved this ?

Comment: No. Not yet. I am still getting this error.

Comment: can you edit your question to show what command are you typing on your cmd ?

Comment: Snap: cmake -DOpenCV_DIR:PATH=F:Sandeep\
CI2CV\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin F:\Sandeep\CI2CV\face-analysis-sdk-stable\build
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Comment: did you try the GUI-cmake ?

Comment: No. Will try that. Did it work for you?

Comment: yes it generated a visual studio project,

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable OpenCV_DIR and set that to the location where OpenCVConfig.cmake is:

```
cmake -DOpenCV_DIR:PATH=C:/opencv ..
```

Comment: I have already set the path to `OpenCVConfig.cmake` at `opencv/build`, and I am still getting the same error, any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Add to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR THE_PATH)
```